# how do you create organizned sections in knitr

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to include sections in knitr and I am seeing a strange behavior:

This is the heading of the file:

---

```
title: "cpu usage document"
date: "October 29, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
    highlight: zenburn
keep_tex: true
---
```

in side of the chunks I have something like this:

```
cat("# cpu1 Bound \n")
print(ggplot output here)
cat("# memory1 Bound \n")
print(ggplot output here)
cat("# cpu2 Bound \n")
print(ggplot output)
cat("# memory2 Bound \n")
print(ggplot output)
```

When I compile the knitr

I see something like this.

```
1. cpu1 bound
ggplot chart
2.memory bound
3.cpu2 bound
4.memory2 bound
ggplot output for memory1
ggplot output for cpu2
ggplot output for memory2
```

what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to create sections in knitr?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? Why are you putting headings in `cat`?

Comment: output should be under each heading, there should be corresponding ggplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper Markdown — don’t use `cat`, nor `print`.

````
## cpu1 Bound

```{r}
ggplot output here
```

## memory1 Bound

```{r}
ggplot output here
```

## cpu2 Bound

```{r}
ggplot output here
```

# memory2 Bound

```{r}
ggplot output here
```
````

(Also note that I’ve used level 2 headings, as level 1 headings usually correspond to the document title, and hence should be used only once, at the beginning.)

Comment: I have have to use cat and print, other wise it is not working for me, I need to turn off comments etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, not working for me the same behaviror

Comment: @user1471980 It’s entirely unclear what you’re attempting to do, then. My answer solves the exact problem that your comment under the question poses.